# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable when trying to use a specific math equation

Tags: python-3.x, math

I have an assignment for a university course that I'm doing and I need assistance on why I'm getting this TypeError.

The original equation is:
**Surface Area = 3√(25 + 10√5) * ^2**

```
a = input("Edge Length: ")

suface_area = (3 * math.sqrt(25 + (10 * math.sqrt(5)) (a) ** 2))

print(surface_area)
```

I expect the written code to give me an output of the calculated "Surface area" that this equation is supposed to provide me, however I keep getting the TypeError message when the program tries to execute the code.

Please give me feedback on what I should try to fix this.
Thanks!

Comment: You are missing the multiplication operation `*` before `(a) ** 2`.

Comment: oh dang haha, cheers for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two tiny issues with your code is causing problems.

1. You're missing a `*` in before `(a)**2` in `suface_area = (3 * math.sqrt(25 + (10 * math.sqrt(5)) (a) ** 2))`.
2. You misspelled the variable name `suface_area` when your `print` function is being told to print`surface_area`.

Hope this helps!